# Java: which and whereis show different locations from actual installation directory

Tags: command-line, java

I installed `jdks` in `/usr/lib/jvm`, and accordingly changed `/etc/environment` for `JAVA_HOME`.

I then do:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

So even though I install `jdks` in `/usr/lib/jvm`, `which` and `whereis` commands show different locations.

What's the connection here?

Comment: Wherever you maybe installing JDKs, there seems to be a `/usr/bin/java` which `which` finds, and `whereis` thinks these other locations are relevant according to its definition of relevance.